# IUCr paper on Sharelatex - references

Tags: biblatex, sharelatex

I am writing a paper for the Journal of Applied Crystallography using Sharelatex. To manage the references I put them in a .bib file and I added the following lines in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Article.bib}
```

At the end of the paper, I included `\printbibliography` to get the bibliography printed. Things work fine, except that the format I have now is `A. Author et al., "Paper title". In: Journal, Vol (year)`. I would like to change this in `Author, A., Author, B. and Author, C. (year). Journal, Volume`, as required by the journal. How do you suggest to do it?

Answer (score 2):

As detailed in the manual, you can adjust the abbreviations of the author list by setting the `maxnames` option when loading `biblatex`. If that does not help, we will need a more extended example of your input to provide further guidance.